# modelpopup example in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I've tried `modelpopup` but it is not working. Can anybody give me a simple example of its usage?

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
function showList()
{
    var return_value = window.showModalDialog(url, arguments, options);
    if (return_value)
    {
        document.getElementById('A').value = return_value.A;
        document.getElementById('B').value = return_value.B;
    }
}
```

**From Inside Dialog**

```
function makeSelection(a, b)
{
    window.returnValue = { A: a, B: b };
    window.close();    
}
```